# Proof of Gallai Theorem for factor critical graphs

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I am trying to find the proof of the following theorem:

> **Definition 1.2.** A vertex $v$ is *essential* if every maximum matching of $G$ covers $v$ (or $\nu(G-v) = \nu(G)-1$). It is *avoidable* if some maximum matching of $G$ exposes $v$ (or $\nu(G-v) = \nu(G)$). A graph $G$ is *factor-critical* if $G-v$ has a perfect matching for any $v \in V(G)$.
>
> **Theorem 1.3.** Let $G$ be a connected graph. Then $G$ is factor-critical if and only if every vertex is avoidable.

I don't think this is something I can prove on my own. However, I can't seem to find the proof of it online either.

It makes sense intuitively. If for every vertex $v$, in graph $G$, there exists a perfect matching that doesn't include $v$, then removing $v$ and its incident edges would result in a perfect matching because one existed that didn't include $v$ in the first place.

Could someone provide a more formal proof for this theorem, or provide a link to where I might find the proof?

Thank You

Comment: Could you please un-accept the answer by Santana Afton? It is not useful in recovering a logical proof, and misleads one into believing the proof of this theorem is simple. Even the answerer themself agrees that it has a huge gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, suppose that $G$ is factor-critical. By definition, this means that for any vertex $v$ the subgraph $G-v$ has a perfect matching. Let's call that matching $M$. Since $M$ is perfect in $G-v$, it must be maximal in $G$, implying that $v$ is avoidable. Thus, every vertex in $G$ is avoidable.

Now, suppose that every vertex of $G$ is avoidable. This implies that for any pair of vertices, there is no maximum matching that misses both of them. Therefore, any maximum matching must only miss one particular vertex. Let's call that vertex $u$. This implies that $G-u$ has a perfect matching, and hence is factor-critical. Since every vertex is avoidable, this argument holds for every vertex in $G$. This implies that $G$ is factor-critical.

Comment: Wait, why does every vertex being avoidable imply that for any pair of vertices there is no maximum matching that misses both of them? That is nontrivial.

Comment: @Mike Oh, that's a great question. This was clear to me three years ago -- I'll give it some thought. Even if you assume that's true, it feels like the second part of the second paragraph is also not quite right -- how do you have control over which vertex in the pair gets missed?

Comment: this indeed is a challenging problem. I had used these types of results in my dissertation but it was quite a while ago!

Answer (score 4):

A remark: if $M$ and $N$ are matchings of maximal size, the components of the subgraph formed by the edges in $M\cup N$ are even cycles and paths of even length.

The following is due to de Caen.

> Lemma: Suppose $u$ and $v$ are vertices in the graph $X$ such that any maximum matching covers at least one of them. If $M_u$ is a maximum matching in $X$ that misses $u$ and $M_v$ is a maximum matching which misses $v$, there is a path of even length in $M_u\oplus M_v$ with $u$ and $v$ as its end-vertices.

Proof:
Let $H$ be the subgraph formed by the edges in $M_u\oplus M_v$.  The components of $H$ are even cycles and paths and, as both $M_u$ and $M_v$ have maximum size, each path must have even length.

Our hypothesis implies that $u$ is covered by $M_v$ and $v$ is covered by $M_u$.  Hence $u$ and $v$ have valency one in $H$ and therefore they are end-vertices of paths.

Suppose first that they lie on distinct paths and let $P$ be the path containing $u$.  Then $P$ is an $M_v$-alternating path with even length and $M_v\oplus E(P)$ is a maximum matching which misses both $u$ and $v$.

But no maximum matching misses both $u$ and $v$, therefore $u$ and $v$must be end-vertices of the same path from $H$.  As all paths in  $H$ have even length, we are finished.

> Lemma:
> Let $u$, $v$ and $x$ be distinct avoidable vertices in $G$.
> If no maximum matching in $G$ misses both $u$ and $x$, and no maximum matching misses both $x$ and $v$, then no maximal matching misses both $u$ and $v$.

Proof:
Let $M_x$ be a maximum matching that misses $x$ and suppose that $N$ is a maximum matching that misses both $u$ and $v$. By de Caen's lemma applied to $u$ and $x$, there is an alternating path in $M_x\cup N$ joining $u$ to $x$.  By the same argument applied to $x$ and $v$, there is an alternating path from $x$ to $v$ in $M_x\cup N$.  Since
there can be only one alternating path in $M_x\cup N$ starting at $x$, this implies that $u=v$, a contradiction. Therefore there is no maximum matching in $G$ that misses $u$ and $v$.

> Lemma (Gallai):
> If $X$ is connected and each vertex is missed by a maximum matching, then for each vertex $v$ the graph $X\setminus v$ has a perfect matching.

Proof:
As $X$ is connected and all vertices are avoidable, from the previous lemma and a simple induction argument, we see that no two vertices of $G$ are missed by a maximum matching.  Therefore each maximum matching
of $G$ misses exactly one vertex.

Comment: This is not a complete proof though. How do you know that a maximum matching covers at least 2 of $u$ and $v$? That doesn't seem clear to me at all.

Comment: @mike: it's not clear which part of the proof you are referring to.

Comment: @misha lavrov: I don't follow the distinction between "maximal" and "maximum" (but I've changed it). I realise it's standard, but it really confuses students. I prefer to say maximum/maximal by size, versus max by inclusion.

Comment: In the hypothesis of de Caen's lemma, every matching covers at least one of $u$ and $v$. In the hypothesis of the second lemma is a pair of vertices $u$ and $x$ such that at least one is covered by every maximum matching. [And then I am not following the proof of the last lemma by Gallai here.]

Comment: @ChrisGodsil It's true that I have to apologize to students every time I mention the distinction (and I try not to give them assignments that "catch them out" on not remembering it). It's unfortunate that people make it all the time, especially with matchings. Your argument is very nice, either way!

Comment: @Mike If you have two adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$, at least one is covered by every maximum matching, otherwise you could add the edge $uv$. If all our vertices are avoidable, then you can apply the second lemma to prove the same for vertices at distance 2, then at distance 3, and so on.

Comment: Now in fact if $u$ and $v$ are *adjacent* vertices then any maximum matching has to cover at least one of $u,v$. And you can use your second lemma and induction to show the following.....

Comment: @Misha Lavrov I do see that point now, as I was typing out the comments. It is quite a nice argument, cleaner than what I came up with. But this point didn't seem clearly illustrated in the proof as it was written. I can't be the only one who had read this and was not able to follow.

Comment: Again it is a nice line of reasoning, I just think the main point could be editted to be a bit clearer

Comment: Can I have a link or reference(s) to read more about the de Caen lemma?

Comment: @holola: I think it's in "On a theorem of Koenig on bipartite graphs", J. Comb. Inf. Syst. Sci., Vol. 13 (1988) 127. (Only one page!) What I wrote was based on conversations with de Caen (who was a personal friend), and my own notes.

Answer (score 3):

This can be proved quickly using the [Tutte-Berge formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte%E2%80%93Berge_formula). For a subset of vertices $U \subseteq V$, let $q(U)$ denote the number of odd components of $G - U$. The Tutte-Berge formula states, in effect, that there is some $U \subseteq V$ such that a maximum size matching of $G$ avoids exactly $q(U) - |U|$ vertices. Now it is easy to see that any matching of $G$ avoids at least $q(U) - |U|$ vertices of $G-U$: from each of the $q(U)$ odd components at least one vertex must be either unmatched or matched to a vertex in $U$, and the latter can happen for at most $|U|$ vertices.
It follows that the vertices in $U$ are not avoidable, so by assumption $U$ must be empty. Then, since $G$ is connected, $q(U) - |U| = q(U)$ is either $0$ or $1$. The former would mean that $G$ has a perfect matching, so that none of the vertices are avoidable, a contradiction. So every maximum matching avoids exactly one vertex, which, together with the assumption that every vertex is avoidable, implies that $G$ is factor-critical.

In general, the behaviour of the set of avoidable vertices is described by the so-called Edmonds-Gallai decomposition of the graph, see e.g. Theorem 2 of [these lecture notes](https://math.mit.edu/%7Egoemans/18438F09/lec3.pdf). Gallai's Theorem immediately follows from this decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

We prove the following:

> THM: Let $G$ be a connected graph where for each vertex $v \in G$
> there is a maximum matching that does not contain $v$. Then $G \setminus \{v\}$
> has a perfect matching for each
> $v \in V(G)$.

First of all, the graph must be *connected* for this to be true. Indeed,
2 vertex-disjoint copies of a graph where all vertices are avoidable
also has this property, and the maximum matching leaves at least
2 vertices uncovered. Secondly, this seems challenging to prove. I
apologize for the length, I don't know how to make this any shorter.

We make the following claims:

> Claim 1: Let $M^*$ be any maximum matching. Then for any vertex $v$ matched
> by $M^*$ at most 1 of $v$'s neighbors are not matched by $M^*$.

*Proof of Claim 1*: Let us suppose that there is a vertex $v$ and a
matching $M^*$ not covering at least 2 of $v$'s neighbours which we
write as $u_1$, $u_2$. Then let $M^*_v$ be a maximum-cardinality
matching not covering $v$. Then $|M^*_v|=|M^*|$ Then as
$M^*_v$ and $M^*$ are both maximum matchings and $v$ is covered by $M^*$ but not by $M^*_v$, the component $P$ of $M^*_v \cup M^*$ that contains $v$ is a path with (i)
one of its endpoints $v$, and (ii) $|P \cap M^*| = |P \cap M^*_v|$.
Furthermore, each of $u_1,u_2$ is also the endpoint of a path
[or is an isolated vertex] of a component of $M^*_v \cup M^*$. So at
least one of
$u_1,u_2$, say $u_1$, is not in $P$ with $v$. So let $M'_v$ be the set of edges where

(a) $M'_v \cap P$ is the $|M^*_v \cap P|$ edges of $M^*_v \cap P$, plus

(b) $M'_v \setminus P^*$ is the set of $|M^*|-|M^* \cap P|$ $=$ $|M^*|-|M^*_v \cap P|$ edges of $M^*$ that are not in $P$.

Then $|M'_v|=|M^*|$ and leaves exposed both $v$ and $u_1$.
Thus $M'_v + \{u_1v\}$ is a matching with cardinality strictly larger
than $M^*$, contradicting that $M^*$ is a maximum matching. So Claim 1
follows. $\surd$

---

Now let $v$ be a vertex covered by $M^*$.
We now define an ***$(v,M^*)$-alternating path*** to be a path
$P$ where

(i) one endpoint of $P$ is $v$,

(ii) the edge in $P$ incident to $v$ is not
in $M^*$, and

(iii) every alternating edge in $P$ is in $M^*$ [so the edge in
$P$ incident to $v$ is not in $M^*$, but the next edge is in
$M^*$, but the edge after that is not in $M^*$, and so on and so forth].

---

> Claim 2: Let $v$ be a vertex matched by $M^*$. Then for some vertex
> $y(v)$ not covered by $M^*$ there is a $(v,M^*)$-alternating path
> from $v$ to $M^*$.

*Proof of Claim 2*: Let $M^*_v$ be a maximum matching that leaves $v$
uncovered. Then the component $P$ of $M^*_v \cap M^*$ is a path with one
endpoint $v$. As $M^*_v$ has the same cardinality as $M^*$ and does not
contain the edge in $M^*$ covering $v$ it follows that alternating edges
of $P$ are in $M^*$ that the other endpoint of $P$ is
not covered by $M^*$. $\surd$

> Claim 3: Let $M^*$ be a maximum matching in $G$.
> For each $v$ matched by $M^*$ there is exactly one vertex
> $y(v)$ not matched by $M^*$ there is a $(v,M^*)$-alternating path
> with one endpoint in $v$ and the other endpoint in $y(v)$.

*Proof of Claim 3*: Let us suppose otherwise. Let
$P_1$ be a $(v,M^*)$-alternating path
where the other endpoint is in $y_1$; where $y_1$ not covered by $M^*$;
a path $P_1$ exists by Claim 2.
And let $P_2$ be a $(v,M^*)$-alternating path
where the other endpoint is in $y_2$; where $y_2$ not covered by $M^*$.
Let us assume that $P_1$ and $P_2$ do not intersect except at $v$.
[Otherwise there is a vertex $v'$ on $P_1 \cap P_2$
that is covered by $M^*$ so that there is a $(v',M^*)$-alternating path
$P'_1$ where the other endpoint is in $y_1$, and a
$(v',M^*)$-alternating path $P'_2$ where the other endpoint is in $y_2$, and $P'_1$ and $P'_2$ intersect only at $v'$.
Namely $P'_1$ is $P_1$ from $v'$ to $y_1$ and $P'_2$ is $P_2$
from $v'$ to $y_2$.]

Then let $M'$ be the matching formed from $M^*$ where (i) the edges in
$M^* \cap P_1$ are replaced by those in $P_1 \setminus M^*$ except
for the one edge in $P_1$ incident to $v$, and (ii) the edges in
$M^* \cap P_2$ are replaced by those
in $P_2 \setminus M^*$ except for the one edge in $P_2$ incident
to $v$. Then because $P_1$ and $P_2$ intersect only at $v$, it follows that $M'$ is indeed a matching and has as many edges as
$M^*$ so $|M'| \ge |M^*|$; and furthermore $v$ is still covered by $M'$.
Also, 2 of $v$'s neighbours $u_1$ and $u_2$ [namely $u_1$ is $v$'s
neighbor on $P_1$ and $u_2$ is $v$'s neighbour on $P_2$] are *not*
covered by $M'$. So finish by Claim 1. $\surd$

> Claim 4: Let $uv$ be an edge in $M^*$. Then $y(v)=y(u)$.

*Proof of Claim 4*: Let $P_1$ be a $(u,M^*)$-alternating path that ends
in $y_1$; where $y_1$ not covered by $M^*$, and let $P_2$ be a
$(v,M^*)$-alternating path that ends in $y_2$; where $y_2$ not covered
by $M^*$; and $y_1 \not = y_2$. If $P_1$ and $P_2$ intersect then there
exists a $(v,M^*)$ path from $v$ to both $y_1$ and $y_2$;
finish as in the proof of Claim 3.

If $P_1$ and $P_2$ do not intersect then $P=P_1 \cup \{uy\} \cup P_2$
is a path where alternating edges in $P$ are in $M^*$ and
where the endpoints of $P$ are not covered by $M^*$. So the matching
$M'$ formed from $M^*$ by replacing the edges in $P \cap M^*$ with those
in $P \setminus M^*$ is indeed a matching and has one more edge than $M^*$
does. $\surd$

---

We now finish the proof by showing that $M^*$ leaves only 1 vertex uncovered. Let us suppose that there are at least 2 unmatched
vertices $y_1$ and $y_2$ be $M^*$. Then as $G$ is connected,
let $P$ be a path where one endpoing is an unmatched vertex $y_1$
and the other endpoint is another unmatched vertex $y_2$ and where
every other vertex is matched by $M^*$. Now write $P=y_1v_1\ldots v_ry_2$
where $v_1,\ldots, v_r$ are covered by $M^*$. Then defining $y(v)$ as in
Claim 3, we note the following: $y(v_r)=y_2$
and $y(v_1)=y_1$ and each vertex $v_i$ has exactly one such $y(v_i)$
by Claim 2 so there exists an $i$ such that $y_1=y(v_i) \not = y(v_{i+1})=y_2$
So let $P_{i}$ be a $(v_i,M^*)$-alternating
path from $v_i$ to $y_1$ and let $P_{i+1}$ be a $(v_{i+1},M^*)$-alternating
path from $v_{i+1}$ to $y_2$.

If $v_iv_{i+1}$ is in $M^*$, then finish as in Claim 4.

If $v_iv_{i+1}$ is not in $M^*$ then writing as
$u_{i+1}v_{i+1}$ be the edge in
$M^*$ incident to $v_{i+1}$, by Claim 4 it follows
that $y(u_{i+1})=y(v_{i+1})=y_2$. But then
it follows that there is a $(v_i,M^*)$-alternating path $P$
from $v_i$ to $y_2$ as well as $y_1$; namely the first two
edgres in $P$ are $v_iv_{i+1}$ and $v_{i+1}u_{i+1}$. So finish
via Claim 3.

Thus $M^*$ indeed leaves only 1 vertex unmatched, and as we are given that for each vertex $v$ there is a matching $M^*_v$ that does not cover $v$ and that satisfies $|M^*|=|M^*_v|$, the theorem follows. $\surd$